# PowerShell where object

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to do something fairly simple - I have a string array with multiple elements. I want to create another string array with the elements that don't contain a certain substring.

Unfortunately using both `-notlike` and `-notcontains`, my `$l` returns no entries. I expect it to return one entry with "two" in it. I suspect I'm doing something simple wrong, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

```
$s = "one","two"

Write-Host "s:"

Write-Host "$s"
```

I have tried both -notlike and -notcontains and both return $l as empty. I am NOT using both at the same time.

```
#$l = Where-Object ($s -notlike "on")

$l = Where-Object ($s -notcontains "on")

Write-Host "l:"

Write-Host "$l"
```

Again, I am wanting $l to return with one element "two" since "on" is matched in "one".

Comment: I believe an array should be declared like this: `$s = @('one','two')`. Next, try putting an asterisk inside your double quotes: `$l = Where-Object ($s -notcontains "*on*")`. I'm not sure if this will work actually but it's something you can try :) Mark Wragg posted a good answer

Answer (score 4):

`-NotLike` will work, but you need to use curly braces around your expression in the `Where-Object` (you are currently using brackets) and you need to use a `*` as a wildcard character.

In the `Where-Object` you also need to use `$_` as your variable. This is a special automatic variable that represents the current item in the pipeline as it is being processed (for example, "one", then "two"):

```
$s = "one","two"
"s: $s"

$l = $s | Where-Object { $_ -notlike "on*"}
"l: $l"
```

Answer (score 3):

@Mark Wragg's comments and answer are spot on with regard to the wildcard syntax required for the `-notlike` operator.

Beyond that, the `Where-Object` clause isn't necessary at all, since the comparison operators will also operate as filters when used against an array:

```
$s = "one","two"
"s: $s"

$l = $s -notlike "on*"
"l: $l"
```

Comment: I did try that actually but doesn't it result in a true/false result?

Comment: Ah no I didn't try it with -notlike, I tried it with -notcontains. Good answer, have an upvote :).

Comment: It works as a test (returns true/false) if used against a scalar (single item). It works as a filter when used as an array operator.

Comment: This becomes a risky solution if there's a chance your input might change from being an array to being a single item. Which I guess you could address by doing `$l = @($s) -notlike "on*"`

Comment: There is the potential for unintended consequences.  You can mitigate that by explicitly forcing the LH side to be an array, e.g. $l = @($s) -notlike "on*"

Comment: A big thank you to you both!  I ended up going with:   [code] $l = @($s) -notlike "*on*"

Comment: No problem. FYI you can mark an answer as accepted to show people which solution you went with. Just click the tick icon underneath the voting buttons of the answers.